# Mobile Test Workbench - Using browser to playback tests

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I'm using worklight 6.2 and mtww 8.6, and like the subject says, I would like to know if it is possible to use my browser to playback some tests I've previously recorded.

My app fully functions on the browser, so that is not a issue, I would like to know if it is possible to include the browser on functional tests and if so, how do I do it.

I've tried to add a webapp application to MTWW with the common resources url from my WL app, and it recomended me to install rational test workbench.

Can anyone point me to some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only available in RTW (Web UI testing), not in MTWW. this is why you are prompted.